# Can centerim support multiple jabber accounts?

Tags: command-line

I've been trying to use more CLI programs lately and have been messing around with centerim. After a bit of messing around I've successfully managed to get my google talk account working on it, but I was wondering if it's possible to have multiple jabber accounts with centerim. I would like to replace my GUI IM with centerim and unless I can get multiple jabber accounts I won't be able to.

On a side note, I can't seem to get my AIM account to connect either... My credentials are correct but I think the login server might be wrong. Any help with this part would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is on their [TODO list](http://www.centerim.org/index.php?title=CenterIM4_Feature_Requests#Core_system). It is not probable that it will get done though, since the request has been there for more than 5 years.